# Using ember.js in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js

So, I am new to Ember.js (and web dev in General), I wanted to use Ember.js in my Rails app for some dynamic front-end that will persist data to the back-end (if i described correctly !).

I've been looking for examples on how to use Ember.js in a Rails app, All the resources i've found so far, are only describing how to "Add ember.js", just like adding the gem "ember-rails" etc..

http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/01/24/beginning-ember-js-on-rails-part-1/

this example showes exactly how to build a model, view, controller, with ember.js, and use it in Rails app! this is what i need to get started !

Any help or advice is highly appreciated !

What i really need is, an example that uses Ember.js Side by side with Rails, just like the link i gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[emberWatch.com](http://emberwatch.com/) is doing a great job listing all the resources and tutorials about ember, also look at [ember-rails gem](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails) to easily integrate ember into your rails project

Comment: I think I've explained what i want wrong, I am After a CRUD implementation, And i find this link pretty helpful , hope some one might find it useful as i did:
https://github.com/ddewaele/emberjs-crud-rest

Answer (score 0):

What should be the answer to his question is use `ember.js` as a front end framework and use `Ruby on rails` for the server side. Make a API application using `Ruby on Rails` and then use `ember.js` as your front-end framework.